# c# web service for to assign database table to javascript array

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, c#-3.0

Can you guide me how to do
c# web service for to assign database table to JavaScript array ?
Export Database table to JavaScript array

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Depends on what your web service returns.

Comment: @CnuVas, you need to show some effort, what is your `webservice` code and how you are interacting with that from `javascript`, i would suggest create MCVE example - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, point to `where you stuck`, else this question is `too broad`.